# How to slice a array and assign values to a matrix in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, slice

```
y = [[0,0,0],
     [0,0,0]]

p = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

y[0] = p[0,2]
y[1] = p[3,4]
```

Returns error
I want to assign values in `p` to `y`, how to do that?

The answer should be `y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

Thank you very much!

Comment: First of all, it would be nice to know the language you are working in.

Comment: Python, I want to slice p and put each in y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array slicing is using the wrong syntax. It should be:

```
y[0] = p[0:3]
y[1] = p[3:6]
```

1. Use `:` to slice arrays. Using `,` goes between dimensions, and `p` is not a 2-dimensional array!
2. End slices include the start, exclude the end. So `0:2` has only elements `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, colon (:) is used to slice arrays: I think this is what you are looking for:

```
y = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
p = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y[0] = p[0:3]
y[1] = p[3:6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y = []
p = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

y.append(p[:3])
y.append(p[3:])

print y 

--output:--
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

If you don't specify a value in the first position of a slice, python uses 0, and if you don't specify a value in the second position of a slice, python grabs the remainder of the list.